# Get newsletter subscribed on customer save

Tags: magento2, magento2.3, event-observer, newsletter, newsletter-subscriber

I am trying to get the value of 'if newsletter subscribed' on customer save. I am using the event: `customer_save_after_data_object` for customer update and tried to get the subscription value by this piece code

```
protected $_subscriber;
public function __construct(
    \Magento\Newsletter\Model\Subscriber $subscriber
) {
    $this->_subscriber= $subscriber;
}
public function myUserDefinedFunction() {
    $checkSubscriber = $this->_subscriber->loadByEmail($customer->getEmail());
    $checkSubscriber->isSubscribed();
}
```

Though it is giving the before saved value for the subscription status. I've also tried by adding another event `newsletter_subscriber_save_before`, but no luck. Is there any other solution to get the desired result?

Answer (score 0):

**Try with below**

```
/**
     * Subscriber factory
     *
     * @var SubscriberFactory
     */
    protected $_subscriberFactory;

public function __construct(
    ...
    \Magento\Newsletter\Model\SubscriberFactory $subscriberFactory
    ...
){
    ...
    $this->_subscriberFactory = $subscriberFactory;
    ...
}

public function myUserDefinedFunction() {
    $subscriber = $this->_subscriberFactory->create()->loadByEmail($email);
    if ($subscriber->getId(){
      echo __("This email address is already subscribed");
    }

}
```

[**Update**]

Change state of the subscription, right at the time the customer is saved from the admin end.

**1. app/code/Stackexchange/HideShip/etc/adminhtml/events.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Event/etc/events.xsd">
    <event name="customer_save_after_data_object">
        <observer name="change_subscriber_state"
                  instance="Stackexchange\ModuleName\Observer\CustomereditPost"/>
    </event>
</config>
```

**2. app/code/Stackexchange/HideShip/Observer/CustomereditPost.php**

```
<?php

namespace Stackexchange\ModuleName\Observer;

use Magento\Framework\Event\Observer as EventObserver;
use Magento\Framework\Event\ObserverInterface;
use Magento\Newsletter\Model\SubscriberFactory;
use Magento\Newsletter\Model\Subscriber;

class CustomereditPost implements ObserverInterface
{
    protected $_subscriberFactory;

    public function __construct(
        SubscriberFactory $subscriberFactory
    )
    {
        $this->_subscriberFactory = $subscriberFactory;
    }

    public function execute(EventObserver $observer)
    {
        $email = "demo@test.com";
        $subscriber = $this->_subscriberFactory->create()->loadByEmail($email);
        if ($subscriber->getId()) {
            echo __("This email address is already subscribed");
        } else {
                //$this->_subscriberFactory->create()->subscribe($email);
            $this->_subscriberFactory->create()
                ->setStatus(Subscriber::STATUS_SUBSCRIBED)
                ->setEmail($email)
                ->save();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: It is giving the same result, i.e, the state of `subscription` before saving the customer. I require the changed state with every time the customer object is saved. For now, I've simply used `$this->request->getParam('subscription')` to get the current change of subscription with customer form submission

Comment: This is the generic method to check whether a customer is  subscribed or not. You can use that code based on your requirement. Still you have any query, update your question with other code as well.

Comment: Your answer is correct to check if a customer is subscribed to the newsletter or not, at any random time. Though it is giving the same result as my code in the question is giving. I wanted the changed state of the subscription, right at the time the customer is saved from the admin end.

Comment: Check my updates answer as well. If you need help, let me know.